# OctoberCMS It possible if i'd like to return view of theme on routes.php

Tags: octobercms

It possible if i'd like to return view of theme on routes.php.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Look into setting the URL for your pages to configure a route to that particular page (view): http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/pages#url-syntax